# unittest for reactjs component fails on function passed as props

Tags: reactjs, chai, enzyme, chai-enzyme

I am trying to write a unit test for a simple component that wrote.

Here is my component:

```
const ErrorWrpper = (props) =>(
<div className={props.class} style={props.validateForm(props.inputType)?
{display: 'none'}:{}}>
<span>{props.message}</span></div>
)
 export default  ErrorWrpper;
```

And here is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from '../../test_helper';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { it, describe, beforeEach } from 'mocha';
import  ErrorWrapper  from '../../../src/app/components/login/ErrorWrapper';

let errorWrapper;
describe("ErrorWrapper component unit tests", () => {
 function validateForm(test){

}
before(() => {

    errorWrapper = shallow(<ErrorWrapper class="test"  inputType="all" validateForm={this.validateForm}/>);
});


// these tests check that each className that should exist, exists
describe("className check", () => {
    it('should have className test', () => {
        expect(errorWrapper.find('test')).to.exist;
    });
})
})
```

Now when I run it I get this:

```
ErrorWrapper component unit tests "before all" hook:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateForm' of undefined
```

As you see I am trying to feed validateError function as props but still I am getting the error. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why are you using `this` at all in your test component instantiation. *This* should work:

```
errorWrapper = shallow(<ErrorWrapper class="test" inputType="all" validateForm={validateForm} />);
```

Also, there's a typo in your component: `ErrorWrpper` is `ErrorWrapper`, right?
You're also not passing it the `message` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not getting the reference to `this` in your before all hook. Try to use arrow function to define your `validateForm` function so it will auto bind it with `this` reference or you need to bind `validateForm` function manually like `this.validateForm.bind(this)`.